# Insert Multiple Checkbox Into MySQL With Angular JS Front End

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I know that this is a much covered topic, but I am struggling to properly interpret the online answers in relation my problem. Apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am using AngularJS to create my site and have a form that contains a multiple check box field. I am trying to insert the values that a user selects in these checkboxes into a mySQL database using PHP.

When I have tried solutions that I have found here, or in other forums, it makes the submission break with no records submitted to the mySQL database.

Whilst I generally understand how one would go about submitting a multiple check box field to a mySQL database I think that I am struggling to apply these concepts to my current code structure.

My code as it stands is.

**index.html**

```
            <!-- FORM -->
        <form name="plannerRegister" ng-submit="submitForm(plannerRegister.$valid)" novalidate>
            <!-- FIRST NAME -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : plannerRegister.firstname.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" ng-model="plannerData.firstname" required>
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.firstname.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Your first name is required.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- SURNAME -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : plannerRegister.surname.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" ng-model="plannerData.surname" required>
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.surname.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Your surname is required.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- COMPANY -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : plannerRegister.company.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Company</label>
                <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" ng-model="plannerData.company" required>
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.company.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Your company is required.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- MOBILE NUMBER -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : plannerRegister.mobile.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="tel" name="mobile" class="form-control" ng-model="plannerData.mobile" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="13">
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.mobile.$error.minlength && submitted" class="help-block">Number is too short.</p>
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.mobile.$error.maxlength && submitted" class="help-block">Number is too long.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- OFFICE NUMBER -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : plannerRegister.officenum.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Office Number</label>
                <input type="tel" name="officenum" class="form-control" ng-model="plannerData.officenum" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="13">
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.officenum.$error.minlength && submitted" class="help-block">Number is too short.</p>
                <p ng-show="plannerRegister.officenum.$error.maxlength && submitted" class="help-block">Number is too long.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Services Offered -->                
            <label>Services Offered</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="investments" ng-model="plannerData.services.investments"> Investments
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="ltinsurance" ng-model="plannerData.services.ltinsurance"> Long-Term Insurance
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="stinsurance" ng-model="plannerData.services.stinsurance"> Short-Term Insurance
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="taxplanning" ng-model="plannerData.services.taxplanning"> Tax Planning
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="estateplanning" ng-model="plannerData.services.estateplanning"> Estate Planning
                </label>
            </div>                

            <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
            <button type="submit" ng-click="plannerData_submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = ""; 
$database = "plannerregistration";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database,$con);


?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

switch($_GET['action']) {
case 'add_planner' :
add_planner();
break;
case 'get_planner' :
get_planner();
break;
};

function add_planner() {
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$firstname = $data->firstname; 
$surname = $data->surname;
$company = $data->company;
$mobile = $data->mobile;
$officenum = $data->officenum;


print_r($data);
$qry = 'INSERT INTO plannerData (firstname,surname,company,mobile,officenum) values ("' . $firstname . '","' . $surname . '","' . $company . '","'. $mobile .'","' . $officenum . '")';

$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
if ($qry_res) {
    $arr = array('msg' => "Planner Added Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
// print_r($jsn);
} 
else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting planner');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
// print_r($jsn);
}
};

function get_planner() { 
$qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from plannerData');
$data = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
    $data[] = array(
        "id" => $rows['id'],
        "firstname" => $rows['firstname'],
        "surname" => $rows['surname'],
        "company" => $rows['company'],
        "mobile" => $rows['mobile'],
        "officenum" => $rows['officenum']
    );
}
print_r(json_encode($data));
return json_encode($data); 
};

?>
```

**registrationController.js**

```
registrationApp.controller('registrationController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.plannerData = {}
// function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
$scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (isValid) {
        alert('our form is amazing');
    }
}
$scope.plannerData_submit = function() {
    $http.post('scripts/controllers/db.php?action=add_planner', 
        {
            'firstname' : $scope.plannerData.firstname, 
            'surname' : $scope.plannerData.surname, 
            'company' : $scope.plannerData.company,
            'mobile' : $scope.plannerData.mobile,
            'officenum' : $scope.plannerData.officenum            
        }
    )
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("Planner has been Submitted Successfully");
      $scope.get_planner();

    })

    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
}
$scope.get_planner = function() {
$http.get("scripts/controllers/db.php?action=get_planner").success(function(data)
    {
        //$scope.product_detail = data;   
        $scope.pagedItems = data;    

    });
}
});
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for the heads up. I am pretty new to this, so this kind of advice is very useful! I will look through the links you sent and try to rewrite the code. However, am I right in saying that my original query would still be  valid even after I switch to PDO?